# Substituirr espaço por Vírgula

Tags: php, string, variáveis, replace

```
$var = 123 456 789;
```

Preciso que o valor dessa varável fique:

```
$var = 123,456,789;
```

Ou acrescentar uma vírgula após o numero:

```
$var = 123, 456, 789;
```

Tentei assim:

```
str_replace($var," ","")
```

Comment: Faça o inverso: `str_replace(" ",",", $var)`

Answer (score 1):

Você já está quase conseguindo. Os argumentos da função `str_replace` que estão em ordem errada.

Conforme a documentação do PHP que você pode [consultar aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php), você precisa fazer o seguinte:

```
$resultado = str_replace(' ', ',', $var);  // resultado: 123,456,789;
// ou
$resultado = str_replace(' ',', ', $var);  // resultado: 123, 456, 789;
```

Você pode sempre que quiser consultar a referência do PHP que indica funções relacionadas e outros conteúdos importantes em http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira de não esquecer a ordem é:

```
substituir('este', 'por este', 'neste');
```

traduzindo para o PHP

```
str_replace(' ', ',', $var)
```

> $var = 123 456 789; não é numero nem string, portanto vai gerar um erro no PHP

```
 PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '456' (T_LNUMBER) in source_file
```

> Tem que colocar entre aspas para ser tratada como string

```
$var = "123 456 789";

//errado não vai imprimir nada
echo str_replace($var," ","").PHP_EOL;

//substitui espaço por virgula
echo str_replace(" ",",",$var).PHP_EOL;

//substitui espaço por virgula mais espaço
echo str_replace(" ",", ",$var).PHP_EOL;
```

[rodando no ideone](https://ideone.com/1RQCyK)

Answer (score 0):

Para usar o STR_REPLACE tu precisa transformar o conteudo da variavel em string então deve deixar entre aspas os numeros.
Depois tu passa para fazer a substituição dos espaços pelas virgulas no str_replace, mas dai tu precisa passar o valor recebido do replace para uma variavel que vai armazenar o novo valor.
E dai tu pode até separar depois com explode.

```
$var = '123 456 789';
$texto = str_replace( ' ', ', ', $var );
echo $texto;
$array = explode( ',', $texto );
var_dump($array);
```